# pandas Python Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed in query method

Tags: python, pandas

I'm tring to run:

```
import pandas as pd
df_data = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,20,None,40,50]})
df_data.query('a.isnull()')
```

and an error happens :

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

but:

```
df_data.a.isnull()
```

has no error at all,
why is this happening?
can you help me to figure out why?

Answer (score 12):

Use `python` engine, or use a `np.array` with the default `npexpr` engine.

```
df_data.query('a.isnull()', engine='python')
```

or

```
df_data.query('a.isnull().values')
```

(Not quite sure why `numexpr` can't handle a `pd.Series` though)

Comment: On why pd.Series might not be able to be handled by *insert wherever it used to work*, some recent-ish changes that make pandas structs less like numpy dataframes is probably the culprit.  Numpy just probably handled it gracefully in the conversion.  I've gotten the error before "Error: Object of type <Pandas.Dataframe> is not a Pandas.Dataframe" in the midst of that happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `!=`

```
df_data.query('a!=a')
Out[10]: 
    a
2 NaN
```

Since `np.NaN` not equal to `np.NaN`

Comment: I get `ValueError: unknown type object` when trying this.